# Pyrogram forward + edit message

Tags: python, telegram, pyrogram

How can I make it so that the text can be changed in the forwarded message in PYROGRAM?

```
@app.on_message(filters.chat(publics))
def new_channel_post(client, message):
    message.forward(private_public)
```

A message is sent to a private public and I haven't figured out how to change it.

```
@app.on_message(filters.chat(publics))
def new_channel_post(client, message):
    client.send_message(private_public, message.text)
```

This code captures only text, without hyperlinks.

Answer (score 2):

Forwarded messages cannot be edited. Neither by the original author, nor by the user forwarding. If you need, you can copy a message ([`app.copy_message()`](https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/methods/copy_message)), in which case the forwarded message will look as though you sent the message yourself and will not link back the the original user/channel.

An example flow could look like this:

```py
@app.on_message(filters.chat(public))
def new_channel_post(_, message):
    copy = message.copy(private)
    copy.edit(new_text)
```

[`Message.copy()`](https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/bound-methods/Message.copy) is the a method making `app.copy_message()` easier to use. It returns the copied message, which can be bound to a variable and edited.